# R: Remove line connecting first and last point in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am using R, package plotly and I have problem with connecting first and last point in my graph. I want to avoid it. The code is following:

```
graph<-plot_ly(data, x = ~date, y = ~variable, z = ~value, mode="lines")
```

I tried google some solution, but nothing work so far.

The graph looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk9cU.png).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want the lines in variables 1, 2, 3... to be connected to each other, right?

If this is the case, I think what is happening is that plotly is assuming all your data belongs to the same series.

You need to tell it that the data from each variable is a different series. You can do it by mapping the `variable` to an attribute of the line (`color`, `linetype`, `stroke`, etc...).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Create a data set from EuStockMarkets data for this example
# (this is just to put the data in a dataframe in the same format as your dataset. You can skip this part)
df.data <- EuStockMarkets %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(date=time(EuStockMarkets)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(year=as.integer(floor(date))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(day.of.year = ceiling((date-year) * 365)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(date=ymd(sprintf('%4d-01-01', year))+ days(day.of.year)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-year, -day.of.year) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-date, names_to = "variable") %>%
  dplyr::arrange(variable, date)

plot_ly(data=df.data, x = ~date, y = ~variable, z = ~value, type="scatter3d", mode='lines', color = ~variable)
```

[image]

If you don't want the lines in each `variable` to have different colors, you can use the `split` argument, which will create a different trace (i.e., line) for each value of `variable`. I had to set the color of the line manually otherwise plotly set a different color automatically. I also removed the legend.

```
plot_ly(data=df.data, x = ~date, y = ~variable, z = ~value, type="scatter3d", mode='lines', split=~variable, color=I('black')) %>% layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the first point in you list again, but this time after the last point, then a line between last to first will be added. Or you can add a curve to the plot consisting of the first and last oint only.

Comment: I did this, but this added line only. I want to remove the line between first and last point.